# The last step of a AWS EC2 to S3 file upload

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have this code :
require '/home/ubuntu/vendor/autoload.php';

```
$sharedConfig = [
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
    'version' => 'latest'
];
$sdk = new Aws\Sdk($sharedConfig);
$s3Client = $sdk->createS3();
$result = $s3Client->putObject([
    'Bucket' => 'my-bucket',
    'Key'    => $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"],
    'Body'   => $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]
]);
```

It works, basically. It sends a file to S3. But it apparently sends it badly since it always shows as a corrupted file... Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

To be specific - the image I am uploading is a jpg image and when I try to look at it on the S3 instance, I am told that it "cannot be displayed because it contains errors"

Comment: To be specific - the image I am uploading is a jpg image and when I try to look at it on the S3 instance, I am told that it "cannot be displayed because  it contains errors"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that information. Be as specific as you can in the question.

Comment: Suspect you're supplying the body incorrectly. Expecting to see something like EntityBody::factory(fopen($file, 'r')). Also may want to add 'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg'.